# Get all images from this database table

Tags: database

This is my code. Where I'm wrong?

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD); 
    mysql_select_db($DB_NAME);
    $img = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_bwg_image");

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($img)){
        echo $res;
    }
?>
```

From this table I want to take any pictures.

[image]

Comment: `$res` is probably an object or array, try `print_r($res);` or `var_dump($res);` to see what if anything you are ending up with.

Comment: The `mysql_` extensions has been depreciated in PHP 5.5 and is now removed in PHP 7. See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: I tried to print_r ($ res); But again no result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the global $wpdb for example `$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( “insert sql here");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD); 
    mysql_select_db($DB_NAME);
    $img = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_bwg_image");

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($img)){
        $Image = $res['image_url'];
        echo $Image;
    }
?>
```

You are not declaring the row name from which you want to get data.